# How ListItem.DeleteObject() works?

Tags: development, splistitem, delete, console-application

I have several Lists in my site. Among them I am trying to find out duplicate values in 3 of the lists, **Publisher1, Publisher2, Publisher3**. I am searching in the lists and saving the duplicated objects in a `List<ListItem>`. Now can anyone please explain how `ListItem.DeleteObject()` will work? Do i need to read all those 3 lists one by one and run `ListItem.DeleteObject()` for each list individually? 
Example: In the following Code do I need to read `listData` for each list and go through the `deletedPublishers`for each list.

For your information: `deletedPublishers` is a `List<ListItem>` where I am saving the objects that are duplicate in the lists and need to be deleted.

```
            var deletedPublishers = CheckPublishers(context, columnToCheckDuplicate, lookUpColumn, lookUpTitleColumnName, lookUpIdColumnName);

            for (int i = 1; i <= _numberOfLists; i++)
            {
                var listData = GetPublishers(context, listTitle + i);
                foreach (var deletedPublisher in deletedPublishers)
                {
                    deletedPublisher.DeleteObject();
                    context.ExecuteQuery();
                    Console.WriteLine(deletedPublisher + "row deleted");
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

As per below example code:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using SP = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;

namespace Microsoft.SDK.SharePointServices.Samples
{
    class DeleteListItem
    {
        static void Main()
        {   
            string siteUrl = "http://MyServer/sites/MySiteCollection";

            ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
            SP.List oList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Announcements");
            ListItem oListItem = oList.GetItemById(2);

            oListItem.DeleteObject();

            clientContext.ExecuteQuery(); 
        }
    }
}
```

Using `ListItem.DeleteObject()` you will delete one list item at a time. For a list of ids you can run for loop in the code.

Comment: Actually my question was how to delete items from several lists. Not from one list.